# Query Xpath match first string instead of contain text()

Tags: xpath, normalize-space

I have a xml file like this:

```
<Doc> A0B100 </Doc>
<Doc> A0B101 </Doc>
<Doc> B1A100 </Doc>
<Doc> B1A101 </Doc>
```

I use xpath query to select value of node  that contain "B1"
my code :

```
$txtSearch = "B1";
$titles = $xpath->query("Doc[contains(text(),\"$txtSearch\")]");
```

It returned all 4 value :

```
A0B100 
A0B101 
B1A100 
B1A101
```

But I only want the contain text() to match first string that the result I expected is

```
B1A100 
B1A101
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this xpath

```
Doc[starts-with(normalize-space(text()),\"$txtSearch\")]
```

added `normalize-space()` to trim spaces on your sample xml